# Неверно выполняется скрипт макроса

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Веду семейный бюджет в Google Spreadsheets. Появилась необходимость в значениях типа флажок. Написал скрипт для изменения значения в данной ячейке и заметил неверное его выполнение.
Вот пример скрипта:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('H1').activate();
data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('H1').getValues();
if (data == 'FALSE') {
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
} else {
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
}
```

Поясняю. Если в ячейке типа флажок стоит значение TRUE (установлен флажок), то скрипт выполняется нормально - устанавливается значение FALSE и флажок снимается.
Если ф ячейке стоит значение FALSE (не установлен флажок), то скрипт не выполняется - в ячейке остаётся значение FALSE и флажок не устанавливается.

Вероятно, я написал скрипт неправильно, так как только начинаю изучать данный язык. Заранее прошу за это прощения.

Использую браузеры Firefox и Opera на ноутбуке и Google Chrome на мобильном телефоне.

Comment: Так, а что не так? В чем суть вопроса, что именно не работает, какое поведение вы ожидаете? Я вот не совсем понял, какой у вас вопрос.

Comment: 1. Устанавливаю в ячейке 'H1' значение флажка 'TRUE';
 2. Выполняю код выше;
 3. Значение в ячейке меняется на 'FALSE';
 4. Снова выполняю этот же скрипт;
 5. Значение в ячейке не меняется на 'TRUE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть некоторые подозрения по работе кода. Рассмотрим ваш пример кода и попробуем догадаться, в чем же дело:

```
// получить с таблицы ячейку 'H1' и установить ее активной
spreadsheet.getRange('H1').activate();

// getActiveSpreadsheet() - получить активную электронную таблицу (null - если ее нет)
// getRange('H1') - получить с таблицы ячейку 'H1'
// получить значение ячейки (вот тут может быть массив массивов типа `values[][]`)
data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('H1').getValues();

// если полученное значение (значения) эквивалентны 'FALSE' выполнить первую часть условия
if (data == 'FALSE') {
  // getCurrentCell() - получить текущую ячейку таблицы (которая активна)
  // установить значение ячейки в 'TRUE'
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
} else {
  // вторая часть условия, если у нас в `data` лежит 'TRUE'
  // getCurrentCell() - получить текущую ячейку таблицы (которая активна)
  // установить значение ячейки в 'FALSE'
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
}
```

На первый взгляд код выглядит вполне нормально, но лично мне кажется, что в коде присутствуют лишние операции, которые могут нарушать ожидаемое поведение кода. Судя по начальному коду, в переменной `spreadsheet` хранится таблица, соответственно все, что нам нужно - у нас уже в принципе есть и нам не нужно заниматься активацией ячеек и получением активных таблиц. Попробуем немного изменить исходный код:

```
// получить ячейку 'H1' с таблицы `spreadsheet` (ваша переменная)
var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('H1');
// получить значение ячейки (не `getValues`)
var value = cell.getValue();
// поменяем значение `value` на противоположное и положим его в  переменную `newValue`
var newValue = !value;
// установим в ячейку новое значение, которое лежит в переменной `newValue`
cell.setValue(newValue);
```

Вообще, можно записать этот код в меньшее количество строк (к примеру в две), но это уже на ваше усмотрение. Из советов - читайте доки, к примеру: [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Обязательно воспользуюсь Вашим советом

Comment: Добрый день, Денис! Чуть отредактировал код, который Вы написали в предыдущем сообщении и попробовал применить его. Похоже, что условия всё-таки работают не так, как ожидается. При установленном значении TRUE в ячейке H1 значение не меняется на противоположное.
      var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('H1');
      var value = cell.getValue();
      if (value == 'TRUE'){
        var newValue = !value;
        cell.setValue(newValue);
      }

Comment: @AlexSheeby а какой смысл в блоке `if` если вам нужно противоположное значение? Кстати, возможно у вас что-то с типами данных, возможно вы со строками работаете, а не с булеан

Comment: это же логично - мне нужно, чтобы значение в ячейке TRUE менялось на FALSE, а FALSE не менялось на TRUE. В ячейке тип данных - булеан. Т.е. флажок. Он же галочка. Установлен тип ячейки с помощью пункта меню Вставка --> Флажок

Comment: @AlexSheeby попробуйте условие немного изменить, скажем есть такой хак. ‘if (value.length === 4) { ... }’ это проверка на ‘true’. Возможно проверка кривовата, поэтому не работает.

Comment: К сожалению, такой вид кода тоже не срабатывает. Что примечательно - код без условия работает отлично.

Comment: @AlexSheeby Значит там не строка, а циферка скорее всего. Попробуйте `if (value) { ... }` либо `if (value == 1) { ... }`. А вообще, попробовать бы сделать `console.log(value)` чтобы посмотреть что там

Comment: Этот вариант работает. Просто странно, что не работает проверка  if (value == 'TRUE'). Ведь в строке формул написано именно TRUE при выборе ячейки с флажком. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @AlexSheeby угу, не за что. Если ответ решил проблему - можете отметить его верным )